# Primes of supersingular reduction for non-CM elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

When $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is a non-CM elliptic curve, Serre had shown that there are density 0 primes of supersingular reduction. His proof can be generalized to elliptic curves over arbitrary number fields. This is worked out for example in [Corollary 6.2 of this Arxiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409501.pdf). My understanding is that this claim is regarding the Dirichlet density. A priori, it is not obvious whether the natural density of the set of supersingular primes exists (and is equal to 0).

Q1: Is the same statement true (or expected to be true) for the natural density?

Q2: If yes, is there a reference I could look up?

Edited (after the comments):

Q3: Is it true that for a fixed non-CM elliptic curve $E/F$, the primes in $\mathbb{Q}$ which lie below the supersingular primes in $F$ must also have density 0?

Comment: Corollary 6.2 seems to be stated using the natural density, not the Dirichlet density. The Chebotarev density theorem, which is the main tool, is known with the natural density.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks! Can I therefore conclude that for a fixed non-CM elliptic curve E/F, the primes in $\mathbb{Q}$ which lie below the supersingular primes in $F$ must also have density 0?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: @WillSawin I would appreciate it if you could possibly give a brief reason why this is so.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, that's not actually a simple corollary, it needs its own argument (because non-split primes have density 0 by the usual measurement but primes lying under non-split primes have positive density). I'm pretty sure it can be done, but I don't know if it's anywhere in the literature.